# Android RatingBar weirdness: Whenever I add a RatingBar to my layout, a bunch of the generated tags, throw off errors as if they are undefined

Tags: android, android-widget

Whenever I use a RatingBar view in my layout, I suddenly get all kinds of compile errors. I'm using Android 2.0, but I've also tried 2.0.1, and 2.1, without joy. I also get a message: `Shader 'android.graphics.BitmapShader' is not supported in Layout Editor`,
 and an odd warning which may or maynot be related:
`warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class that doesn't come with an associated EnclosingMethod attribute`

I've tried using the RatingBar both within a tablelayout and outside it, but it behaves the same way. This is very puzzling and frustrating. Please help if you can.

Sincerely,
  Ray

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   >

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/gi_name"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:padding="10px" />
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/gi_description"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="4px" />

<TableLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="4px">

  <TableRow
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="right"
      android:text="@string/GameInfoVerificationLabelText" />
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/gi_verification"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  </TableRow>

  <TableRow
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" >
    <TextView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="right"
      android:text="@string/GameInfoPlayerRatingLabel" />
    <TextView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="  " />
  </TableRow>

  <TableRow
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" >
    <RatingBar
      android:id="@+/gi_player_rating"
      style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_span="2"
      android:isIndicator="true"
      android:numStars="5"
      android:rating="3"
      android:stepSize="1"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
      />
  </TableRow>

  <TableRow
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  >
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/gi_times_played_label"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="right"
      android:text="@string/GameInfoTimesPlayedLabel" />
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/gi_times_played"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="999" />
  </TableRow>


</TableLayout>

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/gi_win_criteria_label"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/GameInfoWinCriteriaLabelText"
  android:padding="4px" />

<TableLayout
  android:id="@+id/gi_win_criteria_table"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="1px"
>
</TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should probably post the XML of the file where you're trying to add the RatingBar.  I'm not using the layout editor (it never works very well for me anyway), but I've successfully used a RatingBar in layout XML.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've added the XML to the original post.
I've already noticed that the Layout Editor has some pretty bad flaws.  It doesn't seem to work with Relative Layout either. It's a shame, because it takes quite a bit longer to test using the emulator.

Comment: The reason I know it's the rating bar is that I've tried commenting out every section of the xml and the only time that fixed the problem was when I commented out the RatingBar. I've also tried moving it outside the table structure, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `android:id` attribute of your RatingBar seems odd:

```
android:id="@+/gi_player_rating"
```

Presumably you meant:

```
android:id="@+id/gi_player_rating"
```

Try fixing that and see if the problem persists.

Comment: doh
I have to go smack my forehead now. Thank you!
Sometimes you just need another set of eyes. Mine are lost in a drawer somewhere.